# Gridview under Repeater control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

i have a repeater control which contains grids, based on values from database, say for example i have 2 grids inside repeater control, now both the grids contains a column which have up and down buttons, now when user clicks on the button from any grids, how can i check from which grid the button is called.
below is my code where i am filling the grids on `RepeaterItemDataBound Event`

```
GridView gvw = e.Item.FindControl("grid") as GridView;
gvw.DataSource = info.GetStories(sectionNames[e.Item.ItemIndex].Trim());
gvw.DataBind();
```

here section name contains the name of the sections, based on number of sections, i generate the grids.
My Design looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGrids" runat="server" 
                        OnItemDataBound="rptGrids_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="5" AllowPaging="true" ShowHeader="true" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="Stories_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleID" HeaderText="Article ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="Category ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText = "Article Title" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PublishDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Publish Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Action" ItemStyle-CssClass="center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnMoveUp" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/up.gif" CommandArgument="Up" CommandName='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + "," + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StoryType") %>' />
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnMoveDown" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/dn.gif" CommandArgument="Down" CommandName='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + "," + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StoryType") %>' />
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/deny.gif" CommandArgument="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this article?');" CommandName='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdStoriesSortOrder" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SortOrder") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <div class="blank"></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

this is my gridviews row_command event

```
protected void Stories_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandName.Split(',')[0]);
    string section = e.CommandName.Split(',')[1].Trim().ToString();
    string command = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    if (command.ToLower() == "up")
    {
        GridView grd = rptGrids.Items[1].FindControl("grid") as GridView; // If i specify the index here, i gets proper grid, but how to recognize at runtime.
        Response.Write(grd.Rows.Count);
    }
    else if (command.ToLower() == "down")
    {

    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i get from which grid up/down button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command argument to pass required value.
Here is sample of using imagebutton in similar way:

```
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnView" runat="server" ToolTip="<% $resources:AppResource,Edit %>"
                    SkinID="EditPage" CommandName="myCommand" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>'
                    PostBackUrl='<%# "~/AdminPages/Customer.aspx?id=" + Eval("CustomerId").ToString() %>' />
```

Take notice on CommandArgument property.You can set it with value that indicates specific gridview inside repeater.

And here is how to check the value:

```
    protected void EntityGridViewContacts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //here you can check for command name...
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "myCommand":
                //here you access command argument...
                int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
        }

        //here is how you access source gridview...
        GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
        string controlId = gridView.ID;
    }
```

You can also set CommandArgument using this approach:

```
CommandArgument='<%# GetMySpecialValue() %>'
```

Then you should declare function on page side something like this:

```
public string GetMySpecialValue() 
{
     return "some value";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregor Primar for your valuable reply, can you please tell me how to pass the gridname inside the repeater, at the design i have placed the single grid inside the repeater, how to name it in commandargument.

Comment: actually it should be GridView.ClientID, because ID will always return Grid as per my above example... anyways very very thanks for you help